# How to get results of stored procedure #1 into a temporary table in stored procedure #2

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I am trying to combine the results of several stored procedures into a single temporary table. The results of the various stored procedures have the same column structure. Essentially, I would like to UNION ALL the results of the various stored procedures.  A significant fact: each of the stored procedures creates a temporary table to store its data and the results each returns are based on a select against the temporary table:

```
create proc SP1    
as
 .
 .  <snip>
 .
 select * from #tmp   -- a temporary table
```

Noting that `select * from OPENQUERY(server, 'exec SP1')` does not work if the select in SP1 is against a temporary table (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293865/using-openquery-exec-stored-procedure-to-create-new-temporary-table-fails-with) for details), is there another way for a different stored proc, SP2, to get the results of executing SP1 into a temporary table?

```
  create proc SP2 as
  -- put results of executing SP1 into a temporary table:
  .
  .
  .
```

NOTE: SP1 cannot be modified (e.g. to store its results in a temporary table with session scope).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your temporary table such that it fits the results of your stored procedures.

Assuming your temp. table is called "#MySuperTempTable", you would do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO #MySuperTempTable (Column1, Column2)
EXEC SP1
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: You don't even have to specify the column list, if not needed.

Comment: Absolutely. You have now seen my anal retentiveness when it comes to writing SQL queries.

Comment: My pet peeve is inserts with no column names...well unless it's filled by a select WITH column names.  I appreciate your Anal Retentiveness

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #MySuperTempTable 
EXEC SP1
```

Following above code style but sqlserver is not compialing instructions.