Concatenating variables into string literals in dynamic query
I can't get this query to work, I've tried adding quotes, removing quotes, different data types. The date format that the sp_report QuickBooks procedure is expecting is {d'yyy-mm-dd'}, and it works perfectly fine when I do this:
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(QODBC,
'sp_report TrialBalance
show D_Title, C_Title, Label, Deb, Cred
parameters DateFrom = {d''2024-01-01''}, DateTo={d''2024-06-30''}, ReportBasis = ''xyz'' ')

But since I want a dynamic query with variable dates, I can't get it to work like this:
DECLARE @From NVARCHAR(10) = '2024-01-01'
DECLARE @To NVARCHAR(10) = '2024-06-30'
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLQuery = '
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENQUERY(QODBC,
        ''sp_report TrialBalance
        show D_Title, C_Title, Label, Deb, Cred
        parameters DateFrom = {d''' + @From + '''}, DateTo = {d''' + @To + '''}, ReportBasis = ''xyz''
    '')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

I have tried using double, single quotes. I'm guessing that this was probably because of the sp_report's date format since it expects a string literal instead of a variable, but I just wanted to confirm and see if there would be any other solution.
My errors are usually:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '2024'
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'Accrual'


To debug dynamic SQL use the PRINT statement and print your dynamic SQL which you can then debug.

Since you're nesting the original query inside another set of ' characters have you tried re-doubling all of the original ' characters?

@Muhammad Naqvi, also check the answer of Saif Khan in this post for possible workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159465/execute-stored-proc-with-openquery

just keep adding 's for every ' until your dynamic sql starts look like the static one, use PRINT @sqlquery to see the results

Try this, I don't have access to QuickBooks database to test this.
DECLARE @VAR char(2)
SELECT @VAR = 'CA'
EXEC MyLinkedServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql
N'SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = @state',
N'@state char(2)',
@VAR

Source: Microsoft Learn Document
Try other ways of passing a variable to a linked server here

This doesn't really address the question, the problem is not calling linked server

@siggemannen - but maybe this could be a way of passing parameters to sp_report that doesn't rely on concatenating them into a string and passing them with ODBC syntax?

I wonder, the code doesn't seem to be of sql server origin. Better go with EXEC('something with ? params', @a,@b,@c) at QODBC stuff if they work

Don't know about QuickBooks but in SQL Server when you need to form a dynamic string like this you could use 4 (four) single quotes that will be interpreted as 1 (one) single quote in concatenated string:
DECLARE @param_1 NVARCHAR(10) = 'Table_1'
DECLARE @param_2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @param_3 NVARCHAR(10)   = '24-08-15'
DECLARE @SQL_CMD NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @SQL_CMD = 
     'SELECT * ' +  
     'FROM ' + @param_1 +
     ' WHERE some_column = ' + '''' + @param_2 + '''' + 
      ' And some_other_column > ' + '''' + @param_3 + ''''
PRINT @SQL_CMD

/*   R e s u l t :
SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE some_column = 'ABC' And some_other_column > '24-08-15'
*/

OR with @sq variable declared as single quote once - the result is the same
DECLARE @param_1 NVARCHAR(10) = 'Table_1'
DECLARE @param_2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @param_3 NVARCHAR(10)   = '24-08-15'
DECLARE @sq NVARCHAR(1) = ''''   /*  @sq is variable holding single quote   */
DECLARE @SQL_CMD NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @SQL_CMD = 
     'SELECT * ' +  
     'FROM ' + @param_1 +
     ' WHERE some_column = ' + @sq + @param_2 + @sq + 
      ' And some_other_column > ' + @sq + @param_3 + @sq
PRINT @SQL_CMD

